# from desktop to web or full stack programmer

Tags: web

I have been a windows application programmer for 8 years now and I'm using VB.net/C# and sql as my programming language in the companies I worked with. I have never done any web development projects and most of the job openings right now is looking for web developers or full stack programmer. Other than VB.NET/C#, how and what should I start to lean to move from windows to web programmer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment.
Based solely on my opinion:

1) Follow the Microsoft technology stack with ASP.NET MVC as the next step. You will use familiar development environment and IDE but will learn a client side and web development basics.

2) Next step could be decoupling from Microsoft client side and using AngularJS with MVC server side.

3) By then you should know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you want to do front end development, learn JavaScript and some front end tools like react, sass, and less.  This assumes that you learn Html 5 and css.

To do web services work, learn .net or java.

"full stack" is both.

Other tools with reasonable jobs include ruby rails, groovy grails, node.js, and about a million others.

The key is to choose a path and start learning stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the web dev. Most companies now are looking for it. Full Stackers need very strong logical capacity and can be very stressfull (I'm 22, most of my hairs are already grey, even the hair in my nose, my beard and moustache).